# Differences in msvc 2010 c++ and gnu c++ (g++-4) in OpenCV 2.4.3

Tags: c++, opencv, pass-by-reference, visual-studio-2010

I have a function in my c++ code that compares two images and removes a static background (somewhat hackish, but works for my purposes):

```
void Keyboard::processBackground( const cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat &foreground )
{
    cv::Mat grey, diff;

    cv::cvtColor( img, grey, CV_RGB2GRAY );

    cv::equalizeHist( grey, grey );

    if ( !initialBackground )
    {
        bg = grey.clone();
        initialBackground = true;
    }
    cv::absdiff( grey, bg, diff );
    cv::threshold( diff, foreground, 75.0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );

    cv::imshow( "foreground", foreground );
    cv::imshow( "background", bg );
}
```

This code works exactly as expected in Ubuntu with g++-4.5, but in msvc 2010 (express), my foreground does not seem to be set once I exit this function (even though it's being passed by reference).

I'm running Windows 8 64 bit, but compiling against the 32 bit libraries (for compatibility reasons).

I have run this code extensively in Ubuntu 12, and it ran as expected (foreground was set), but not in msvc.  Even passing foreground as a pointer doesn't seem to work as expected.

Is this a known quirk, a problem with msvc, or a problem with OpenCV 2.4.3?

Comment: you probably need to call `cv::waitKey` somewhere after `imshow`.

Comment: That does happen, just not in this function.  I'm using the MSVC debugger with multiple breakpoints, and the foreground data memeber is not getting set.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'not set'?

Comment: foreground.data = '', where data is of type `char*`.